# Excel VBA to delete blank rows within a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have worksheet that have data starting at A84, extending to column X. I use this VBA to select the entire range of data.

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = Range("A:Z").Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

Range("A84:X" & Lastrow).Select
```

Within that selected range, I need it to detect which rows are blank from columns A to Z and delete them. If there's data after column Z, the row should be deleted because I'm considering it blank.

Comment: Loop backwards through the range rows: `For i = Lastrow to 84 step -1` then: `If Application.WorkSheetFormula.CountA(Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i,26)))=0 Then Rows(i).Delete`

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm sorry. I might be doing something wrong, but I get a syntax error when I run that.

Comment: What is the error and on which line?

Comment: It just says "Compile error: Syntax error" for `If Application.WorkSheetFormula.CountA(Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i??,26)))=0 Then Rows(i).Delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments sometimes adds characters.  Here is the code:

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = Range("A:Z").Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row


For i = Lastrow To 84 Step -1
    If Application.CountA(Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 26))) = 0 Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. And this is what is highlighted: `If Application.WorkSheetFormula.CountA(Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 26))) = 0 Then`

Comment: Wait. Should it be Application.WorkSheetFunction instead of ApplicationWorkSheetFormula? I made that change, and it works.

Comment: @Robby that's what I get for just typing it in the answer.  Yes, or like the edit above.  Remove the WorkSheetFunction part completely.

Comment: @Robby remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: After testing this some more, I ran into an issue when using Excel 2010: If I had the blank row in view when I run this code, it always deleted the row. But if the blank row wasn't in view when the code was ran, sometimes it didn't delete the row. Instead it just removed the row number from the grey cell, which I thought was weird. I solved this bug by including the WorkSheetFunction bit in that second to last line.

Comment: Wait. I take that last comment back. I'm still having that problem. Any ideas?